# iPhone - Add annotation to My own Map

Tags: iphone

I have an image plan of stores of exhibitors hall. So I need to add annotation to each store in the plan, which is a jpg file.

iPhone MapKit looks like supports only world map. Are there any way I can add my own picture and add annotation to it like google map annotation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that.

What you can do is using a UIScrollView to scroll and zoom in/out your jpg plan and use subviews to simulate annotations. That's what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

`MapKit` does not support custom tiles, so your only option is to implement your own map using `UIScrollView` (and potentially `CATiledLayer` if the map is large / has many zoom levels).